# Finding the coffecient for a generating function

Tags: generating-functions

Let $f(x) = {2 \over {1-2x}}$.

How can you tell the expansion is: $\{2x + 2^2x^2 + 2^3x^3 + ...\}$

I am familiar with the geometric series and I guess there must be a connection between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{1-2x}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k x^k=2+2^2x+2^3x^2+\cdots$$

Comment: Hmm.. How can one know that $1 \over {1-2x}$ is equal to $\sum 2^kx^k$. it looks like out of the blue to me.

Comment: Geometric series... $1+x+x^2+\ldots=\frac1{1-x}$

Comment: Oh right. I got it now.